# Провести линию тренда в графике

Tags: python

Есть файл с двумя колонками (date and position). Делаю из него график через plt все ок. Но не получается провести линию тренда

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('Downloads/quantity.csv')
x = data['date']
y = data['position']
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,p(x),"r--")
data.plot()
print(plt.show())
```

выдает ошибку TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str. Файл [в гугл таблицах](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eo9ZhalPgRLCcKgckasuuQ6GFgswIV0D3ncpNuBMPh8/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Здравствуйте на Stack Overflow на русском! Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы **без явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тренд во временном ряду строиться не от даты, а от тика. У вас-же x-дата -  Series, причем элементы в ней - типа str. Это две, наложившиеся друг на друга ошибки. Исправьте их обе. Думаю, будут и еще.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, могли бы вы поделиться примером?)

Comment: Примером чего? Вы ошибки то исправьте, тогда и можно будет посмотреть что и как надо делать дальше.

Comment: понял, благодарю

Comment: Если поняли и благодарите, то вам, как новичку, подсказываю -  на этом сайте это принято делать несколько другим образом.